# Looking for a word that means encouragement but for ants, a word play

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that is "ant-themed" don't question it hahaha, for a party. And there's this section/corner where we give encouragement to each other, what would be the best word to describe that corner?

Comment: Ant-thusiasm? Why do you expect there to be a word which fulfills your requirements?

Comment: "antcouragement". If you say it fast enough, nobody will notice.

Comment: Dig . Dig dig crawl

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because crossword clues, aardvark-themed words meaning interfrastically etc are not about standard usage but puzzles and trivia.

Comment: Why not *colony* or *colony corner*? That's where ants tend to congregate to offer one another encouragement to overcome the challenges of being ants. :-)

Comment: How about "up the antie"?

Comment: The SCA uses "Vivat!" for encouragement (Interjection vivat A cry wishing someone long life and prosperity).  Go ahead and pronounce it "Vivant!"

Answer (score 1):

How about **antechamber** or **anteroom**? From M-W:

> **[antechamber](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antechamber)**: anteroom
>
> **[anteroom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anteroom)**: a small outer room that leads to another room and that is often used as a waiting room

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite get what you mean by "corner where we give encouragement to each other" - possibly a cultural gap :) - but maybe you can work with sth. along the lines of **(Instant) Assistant(s)**?

Answer (score -1):

**Ant Attributes - Ant-Tributes**

https://www.ghanaweb.com/GhanaHomePage/features/The-ant-as-a-role-model-535492

Ants are self-motivated and hardworking.

Ants plan. Ants understand the weather patterns and act accordingly. They are goal-oriented.

One top observation, in my view, is the unity of purpose that ants demonstrate in a community of sharing.

Note how active and energetic ants are; consider their unity of purpose and sense of community; and admire their discipline and orderly approach to execution of the task at hand. All of us can learn from these observations.